# Find difference in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of email addresses and I am trying to find the difference in the two. One of the arrays contains current email address. The other contains current group members email address. I am updating the group list with the current email addresses and removing the address in the group that are not in the current email addresses. I cannot wrap my head around how I get my `for` loop to accomplish this. Here is my code so far...

```
for(i = 0; i < GROUP_USERS.length; i++){
    var currentMember = GROUP_USERS[i];
    for(x = 0; x < DOMAIN_USERS.length; x++){
      if(DOMAIN_USERS[x] != currentMember){
        continue;
      } else {

      }
    }
```

It seems like I need to test the end of my loop, or something.

**EDIT**

I am using Google Apps Script (SDK). I will have to push all of the emails that need to be deleted to an array and then use the GroupApps class to remove those emails from the group. Then I will need to push the `DOMAIN_USERS` email address that do not already reside in the group, to the group. So, essentially, I will have two arrays. One array of emails that need to be removed from the group and one array of emails that need to be added to the group. Hopefully, that makes more sense.

Comment: Just so you know, `continue` here causes the program to jump back to the beginning of your inner for-loop (the next iteration). It may help if we could see sample `GROUP_USERS` and `DOMAIN_USERS` array values, and what you'd like them to look like in the end.

Comment: @Cory It continues to the next iteration

Comment: Isn't the end result of this that `GROUP_USERS` would be the same as `DOMAIN_USERS`? What do you want to happen if an address is in `DOMAIN_USERS` but not in `GROUP_USERS`, and vice versa? Example of input and desired output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  create another variable to  check currentMember exists in DOMAIN_USERS array 
after that you can remove it from GROUP_USERS array

```
for (i = 0; i < GROUP_USERS.length; i++) {
    var currentMember = GROUP_USERS[i];
    var isContain = false;

    for (x = 0; x < DOMAIN_USERS.length; x++) {
        if (DOMAIN_USERS[x] == currentMember) {
            isContain = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isContain) {
        emailTobeRemove.pop(currentMember);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the logic the same result can be reached with

```
GROUP_USERS = DOMAIN_USERS;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using Google Apps SDK so I cannot just say `GROUP_USERS = DOMAIN_USERS`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to remove all emailaddresses from GROUP_USERS that aren't in DOMAIN_USERS, then add the emailaddresses from DOMAIN_USERS that aren't in GROUP_USERS to the GROUP_USERS array, correct?

You could first make a 'contains' function (for compatability you could use this instead of indexOf()):

```
function contains(arr, val) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === val) {
        return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then to delete all emailaddresses from GROUP_USERS that aren't in DOMAIN_USERS. in a for loop:

```
for(i=0;i < GROUP_USERS.length; i++) {
    if(!contains(DOMAIN_USERS, GROUP_USERS[i])) {
        GROUP_USERS.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Then another for-loop to add the ones from DOMAIN_USERS to GROUP_USERS:

```
for(i=0; i < DOMAIN_USERS.length; i++) {
    if(!contains(GROUP_USERS, DOMAIN_USERS[i])) {
        GROUP_USERS.push(DOMAIN_USERS[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol, or just do what user47448855 said, cause after rethinking the logic you explained he is indeed right and GROUP_USERS will simply become DOMAIN_USERS

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for difference in two arrays
use `grip` and `inarray`
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xES/)

Answer (score 0):

The 2 lists you need are the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of GROUP_USERS in DOMAIN_USERS and of DOMAIN_USERS in GROUP_USERS. So define a function that finds all the members of an array `a` that are not in a second array `b`, and then use that to find which emails need to be added and deleted.

```
function relComp(a, b) {
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (b.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) {
            r.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
var toDelete = relComp(GROUP_USERS, DOMAIN_USERS);
var toAdd = relComp(DOMAIN_USERS, GROUP_USERS);
```

`relComp` can also be written with a filter:

```
function relComp(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return b.indexOf(item) == -1;
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j23drwez/)

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy using open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

[See Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/mvvu9kym/)

```
//Use jsJinq.com open source library
var current = ["a@yahoo.com", "b@yahoo.com", "c@yahoo.com", "d@yahoo.com"];
var group   = ["a@yahoo.com", "d@yahoo.com", "yyy@yahoo.com", "xxx@yahoo.com"];

var currentComplex = [{email:"a@yahoo.com"},{email: "b@yahoo.com"}, {email:"c@yahoo.com"}, {email:"d@yahoo.com"}];

//Gets emails that are in current not in group
var result = jinqJs().from(current).not().in(group).select();
var result2 = jinqJs().from(currentComplex).not().in(group, 'email').select();
```